# Flutter Animation Not Fading (It's Blinking)

Tags: android, ios, animation, mobile, flutter

I'm following along with the the animation tutorial on `flutter` here: https://flutter.io/tutorials/animation/#animationcontroller, and I'm trying to get an icon to fade in and out between purple and orange. Unfortunately all I've managed to do is get an icon to *blink* which seems very frustrating as that is not how the `ColorTween` class is defined. From the docs:

> We recommend that you do not pass Colors.transparent as begin or end
>   if you want the effect of fading in or out of transparent. Instead
>   prefer null. Colors.transparent refers to black transparent and thus
>   will fade out of or into black which is likely unwanted.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/ColorTween/ColorTween.html

I infer this to mean that fading comes "out of the box". However, I have tested this with a `CurvedAnimation` class as well, and it still blinks. I've also tested with a text box, thinking that somehow the fact that it was loading an icon may be messing it up. However, the text value also blinks between orange and purple. In the code below I have it reversing the animation - I also tried ripping that out but that is not affecting the blinking. I'm thinking it may have *something* to do with how I'm setting state, but I'm not sure.

My main tutorial example I am trying to base the below code off of comes from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/_includes/code/animation/animate3/main.dart.

Please see the code below for my implementation. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

```
class CloudAnimation1 extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  CloudAnimation1State createState() => new CloudAnimation1State();
}

class CloudAnimation1State extends State<CloudAnimation1> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  Animation<Color> animation;
  AnimationController controller;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), vsync: this);
    final Animation curve = new CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeOut);
    animation = new ColorTween(begin: Colors.orange, end: Colors.purple).animate(curve);


    animation.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        controller.reverse();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        controller.forward();
      }
      setState(() {
        // the animation object’s value is the changed state
      });
    });
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("hello there sailor",
              style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25.0, color: animation.value)),
          new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.cloud, color: animation.value, size: 40.0)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an AnimatedIcon to actually handle the animation state.

```
class AnimatedIcon extends AnimatedWidget {
  final IconData icon;

  AnimatedIcon({Key key, Animation<Color> animation, this.icon})
      :super(key: key, listenable: animation);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Animation<Color> animation = listenable;
    return new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("hello there sailor",
              style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25.0, color: animation.value)),
          new Icon(icon, color: animation.value, size: 40.0)
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

Then you can replace the build in `CloudAnimation1State` with

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Container(
    child: new AnimatedIcon(
      animation: animation,
      icon: Icons.ac_unit,
    ),
  );
}
```

And then remove the empty `setState` in the animation status listener.

---

Alternatively...

The reason that this is blinking is because `animation.addStatusListener` is only called when the animation status changes, and not on each tick. The `AnimatedWidget` just wraps and abstracts listening for the tick.

Add the following code to your `initState`

```
animation.addListener(() => setState((){}));
```

This callback listens to each tick of the animation and will cause the widget to re-render. Since you want to redraw all the children of this widget each tick, this makes sense. If you only wanted to redraw some of the children, you'd probably want to wrap them in AnimatedWidgets.

You'll still want to remove the `setState` inside of the `addStatusListener` as it is redundant with the new listener.

Comment: You probably shouldn't name the widget `AnimatedIcon`, though, as that's something already in the flutter namespace.